# Unable to run this DEBUG=AATT* http_port=3000 node app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to the node js world. I am trying to execute this command from command prompt and vscode powershell window.These are the commands I had to execute

```
   $ sudo npm install
   $ git submodule init
   $ git submodule update
   $ DEBUG=AATT* http_port=3000 node app.js
```

I executed them as below from windows command prompt

```
npm install
git submodule init
git submodule update
DEBUG=AATT* http_port=3000 node app.js
```

Output:

[image: DEBUG is not recognized as an internal or external command]

Comment: You need a Windows-specific method of setting environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

express is required for this command. after installing express go to app js and set port to 3000 and run node app.js

Comment: Thanks for the response, due to some reasons I still don't see debug recognized in the command line.But however I used Set Debug=AATT* and run my command.